# Delete the [islam] tag on the meta site

Tags: discussion, tag, burninate-request

There's an [islam](/questions/tagged/islam) tag on Islam Meta Stack Exchange; since questions *about* Islam belong on the main site, can we get rid of this tag on the meta site?

Answer (score 1):

The tag is no longer there anymore.